# What does ∧ mean in an equation?

Tags: notation

Note that this is not a caret (^), but rather a ∧. I'm aware it's used as an "and" in logic, but that doesn't seem to fit the context.

Here are some examples it's used in.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: "Wedge product" or "exterior algebra" would be good search terms.

Comment: It is the wedge product. Progress through obfuscation.

Comment: it is also sometimes used as a max operator, but not here

Comment: It's sometimes used to indicate the cross-product

Comment: The latex-symbol is "wedge", i.e., $\wedge$, or $\bigwedge$. So it is the "wedge product".

Answer (score 3):

$\wedge$ is the **wedge product** which is the product in an exterior algebra.